# fancyvrb error with math escapes and prime (')

Tags: math-mode, fancyvrb, mathcode

I've recently noticed a few cases where `fancyvrb` math escapes fail. This works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}]
$f^\prime$
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

But substituting this

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}]
$f'$
\end{Verbatim}
```

fails with the message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
'->\leavevmode \kern \z@ 
                         \char `\'
```

The same sort of error can be produced by trying to use `icomma` with `fancyvrb`.

It isn't hard to work around this, but it would be nice if escaped math didn't have to be checked for such conflicts. I believe this has something to do with the interaction of `fancyvrb` and mathcodes, but I haven't made progress in seeing how that differs from the catcode case.

### Edit

egreg's answer explains things. For anyone working with this in the future, here are a few additional notes.

- See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107760/10742) on the use of `\expandafter` in `\fi*...\fi`.
- See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115427/purpose-of-donoligs-in-latex-verbatim-environment) for more on `\do@noligs`.

Finally, since `fancyvrb` is often used with `upquote`, here is a version of egreg's code that patches the `Verbatim` environment to give primes in math mode and `upquote` single quotes otherwise.  Given the way `upquote` works, both `'` and `` ` `` need to be redefined.  This requires `etoolbox`.

```
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{upquote}%
   {\AtBeginEnvironment{Verbatim}{%
      \apptocmd{\@noligs}%
       {\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
          \ifmmode
            \expandafter\active@math@prime
          \else
            \leavevmode\kern\z@\textquotesingle
          \fi}%
        \ifx\encodingdefault\upquote@OTone
        \ifx\ttdefault\upquote@cmtt
        \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
          \ifmmode
            \expandafter\active@math@prime
          \else
            \leavevmode\kern\z@\char13
          \fi}%
        \fi\fi
        \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\`
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
          \ifmmode
            \expandafter`
          \else
            \leavevmode\kern\z@\textasciigrave
          \fi}%
        \ifx\encodingdefault\upquote@OTone
        \ifx\ttdefault\upquote@cmtt
        \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\`
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
          \ifmmode
            \expandafter`
          \else
            \leavevmode\kern\z@\char18
          \fi}%
        \fi\fi
        }{}{}}}%
   {\AtBeginEnvironment{Verbatim}{%
      \apptocmd{\@noligs}%
       {\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
          \ifmmode
            \expandafter\active@math@prime
          \else
            \leavevmode\kern\z@\char`\'
          \fi}}{}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In verbatim modes, the active `'` is redefined to do

```
\leavevmode\kern\z@\char`'
```

and this will be the definition picked up when `$f'$` is found in such a verbatim mode, even if escaped.

You have to make the definition of the active `'` to be the usual one in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\do@noligs
  {\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
     \ifmmode
       \expandafter\active@math@prime
     \else
       \leavevmode\kern\z@\char`\'
     \fi}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8 }]
$f^\prime$ and $f'$
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had overlooked the effect of `\do@noligs`. Based on [this discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115427/purpose-of-donoligs-in-latex-verbatim-environment) on `\do@noligs`, would it be better to modify `\@noligs` instead of appending to `\do@noligs`, so that the redefinition of `'` is only done once? Also, the other characters in `\verbatim@nolig@list` (`<>,-) seem to be behaving in math escapes. Is there a reason to expect that these characters also need a math mode version?

Comment: @G.Poore The fact is that `'` has mathcode `"8000`, the others don't. One could optimize the definition of `\do@noligs`, but I don't see why one should bother.