# Automatic code ligatures in minted

Tags: minted

In my editor I have liguatures enabled that turn `||` to a `\/` symbol and `lambda` to a λ. I copy-paste a lot of code into the minted environment and its a shame that these do not carry over. Is it possible to tell minted to replace *all* occurances of  `||` with the logical or symbol and all occurances of `lambda` with `\lambda` for example?

I found out that using `fontspec` and `FiraCode` translates the `->` to the character arrow but this does not seem very configurable.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294362 ?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have mentioned FiraCode because that is not the direction I want to go. I don't want to replace character sequences with single unicode characters. I would prefer if I could tell latex to replace some sequences of characters (eg `->`) with other sequences of characters (eg `\to`).

Comment: @fakedrake Will be tricky. Yes, an expl3 `replace` or `regex` can do a substitution, and `minted` when doing the verbatim environment can escape to latex code, but (manual, p24): "Note that when math is used inside escapes, any active characters beyond those that are normally active in verbatim can cause problems." and then links to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223876/fancyvrb-error-with-math-escapes-and-prime  Unrelated: Interestingly, a `%` in a `tex` minted typesets the line as latex, but you have to switch to `\rmfamily` since monospace doesn't have ligatures.

Answer (score 1):

It is a type of meta-processing.

"Telling" is where the effort is.

Example of doing expl3 `replace` by escaping out of `minted`'s verbatim environment and applying a replace-command:

[image: transliteration]

Using unique identifiers, and going directly to (unicode) math glyphs, makes maintenance easier and avoids `minted`'s math-mode glitching.

But probably easier just to type `x ∈ ℜ` in a `unicode-math` space in the first place, without needing to use a lookup command at all, and switching fonts automatically, maybe in an environment-in-an-environment (somehow). `Fancyvrb`'s verbatim environment keeps getting in the way.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\newfontface\mymfont{XITS Math}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmymath}{\mymfont}
\usepackage{minted}

\ExplSyntaxOn



%=====================================
\tl_new:N \l_mytrans_tl 
\NewDocumentCommand { \translit } { m } {%
        \tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
        \dotranslit
        \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
}



%---- Environments
\NewDocumentEnvironment{translite}{ +b }
{
        \tl_set:Nn \l_mytrans_tl { #1 }
        \dotranslit
        \tl_use:N \l_mytrans_tl
}
{ }

%-----   
\newcommand\dotranslit{%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { mlambda }  {  $\lambda$  } 
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { xlambda }  {  \textmymath{}  } % U+1D706 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL LAMDA
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { xreal }  {\textmymath{ℜ} } % U+211C BLACK-LETTER CAPITAL R : real part
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { xelementof }  { \textmymath{∈} } % U+2208 ELEMENT OF
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_mytrans_tl { xmapsto }  { \textmymath{↦} } % U+21A6 RIGHTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR : z notation maplet
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

xlambda $\mapsto$ \translit{xlambda}

\begin{minted}[linenos=true,escapeinside=||]{tex}
% This is a TeX comment but is not disregarded because it's inside
%| {\rmfamily ffi ffl >> -- --- } | font ligatures yes, TeX ligatures no.
| {\rmfamily xlambda = \translit{xlambda} } |

| {\translit{x xmapsto y xelementof xreal}}|
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
Dont use $$ in \LaTeXe!  % It's weird!
\end{document}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```