# Suppress Fira Code ligatures involving “{” and “}” in verbatim

Tags: verbatim, ligatures

I am trying to improve the current implementation (v0.1b) of the [`lstfiracode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lstfiracode) package. In particular, I wish to achieve the *opposite* of [Use Fira Code font with ligatures in code listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294362/164314).

Here is what I have come up with

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.otf}[ % https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases
  Ligatures=Common,Contextuals=Alternate
]

\makeatletter
% Snippets of lstfiracode.sty, v0.1b
\let\lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list\verbatim@nolig@list
\newcommand*\ActivateVerbatimLigatures{%
  \def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\,\do\'}%
}
\newcommand*\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\verbatim@nolig@list\expandafter{%
    \lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list
    \do\w\do\*\do\/\do\:\do\=\do\!\do\~\do\[%
    \do\#\do\(\do\?\do\_\do\.\do\;\do\&\do\|%
    \do\+\do\$\do\@\do\%\do\]% Do "7B and "7D, how?
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ActivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

As shown in the above example, I could not figure out how to `\do\{` and `\do\}`.

As far as I know, simply `\do\{` or `\do\}` messes up category code and the result is a big ⚠. However, the `\do\#` turns out just fine, even though `\do@noligs` has made `#` active before `` \def~{\leavevmode\kern\z@\char`#1} `` and before the other `\do`’s.

What should I do to suppress the Fira Code ligatures involving `{` and `}` (and `\`, just in case)?

Comment: I would say you are misusing the noligs-code (and I don't see how it should work). Why don't you simply remove the `Contextuals=Alternate` if you want to suppress them?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't like this: characters specified in the “nolig list” are made active, but then `\end{verbatim}` doesn't match the terminator sequence, which is expecting `{` and `}` with category code 12.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I absolutely agree. In fact, to avoid ligatures all together, one should simply use Fira Mono instead. I am just wondering if a counterpart of `\ActivateVerbatimLigatures` is possible.

Comment: @egreg Ahhh, this is what I have suspected. It is extremely lucky that `\end{verbatim}` does not contain the lowercase letter `w`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few related questions.

- [Purpose of \do@noligs in LaTeX verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115427/250119)
- [How can I enable ligatures in verbatim environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360533/250119)
- [Use Fira Code font with ligatures in code listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294362/250119)  (opposite question on how to **enable** the ligatures, by emptying out the list)
- [How can I completely suppress ligatures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1841/250119) (how to suppress ligature in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX)
- [How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36692/250119) (how to suppress ligature in PDFLaTeX)

Anyway, in summary,

- if you are okay with disabling ligatures globally for Fira Mono font, just use 4th question above (if XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX) or 5th question above (PDFLaTeX)

Otherwise, keep reading.

---

As mentioned by egreg in the comment, it's because of the matching of the `\@xverbatim` macro.

[image: source2e screenshot]

The only way I can think of is to selectively redefine `\@xverbatim` when needed.

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.ttf}[ % https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases
Contextuals=Alternate
]

\makeatletter
% Snippets of lstfiracode.sty, v0.1b
\let\lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list\verbatim@nolig@list
\usepackage{precattl}
\precattlExec{
\newcommand*\ActivateVerbatimLigatures{%
  \gdef\@xverbatim##1\cO\\end\cO\{verbatim\cO\}{##1\end{verbatim}}%
  \def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\,\do\'}%
}
\newcommand*\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures{%
  \gdef\@xverbatim##1\cO\\end\cA\{verbatim\cA\}{##1\end{verbatim}}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\verbatim@nolig@list\expandafter{%
    \lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list
    \do\w\do\*\do\/\do\:\do\=\do\!\do\~\do\[%
    \do\#\do\(\do\?\do\_\do\.\do\;\do\&\do\|%
    \do\+\do\$\do\@\do\%\do\]\do\{\do\}%
  }%
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ActivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this monkey-patches the `verbatim` environment, so if at any point in time the LaTeX kernel is modified, this will break horribly.

### Explanation

Basically, the normal definition of `\@xverbatim` is:

```
\gdef\@xverbatim#1\cO\\end\cO\{verbatim\cO\}{#1\end{verbatim}}
```

where `\cO\`*⟨character⟩* represents a **other**-category token with charcode = that character.

That matches the document until the specified token list is seen.

When `{` and `}` are made active, then you want to modify the definition to:

```
\gdef\@xverbatim#1\cO\\end\cA\{verbatim\cA\}{#1\end{verbatim}}
```

where `\cA\`*⟨character⟩* represents a **active**-category token with charcode = that character.

---

If you don't want to use my package `precattl`, there are other ways to insert the weird-catcode tokens in. One is to use the catcode-changing trick.

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.ttf}[ % https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases
Contextuals=Alternate
]

\makeatletter
% Snippets of lstfiracode.sty, v0.1b

\let\lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list\verbatim@nolig@list

\begingroup \catcode `|=0 \catcode `[=1
\catcode `]=2 \catcode `\{=12 \catcode `\}=12
\catcode `\\=12
|gdef|ActivateVerbatimLigatures[%
  |gdef|@xverbatim##1\end{verbatim}[##1|end[verbatim]]%
  |def|verbatim@nolig@list[|do|`|do|,|do|']%
]

|catcode `|{|active
|catcode `|}|active
|gdef|DeactivateVerbatimLigatures[%
  |gdef|@xverbatim##1\end{verbatim}[##1|end[verbatim]]%
  |expandafter|def|expandafter|verbatim@nolig@list|expandafter[%
    |lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list
    |do|w|do|*|do|/|do|:|do|=|do|!|do|~|do|[%
    |do|#|do|(|do|?|do|_|do|.|do|;|do|&|do||%
    |do|+|do|$|do|@|do|%|do|]|do|{|do|}%
  ]%
]
|endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ActivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The other is to use `\lowercase` trick.

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode-Regular.ttf}[ % https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases
Contextuals=Alternate
]

\makeatletter
% Snippets of lstfiracode.sty, v0.1b
\let\lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list\verbatim@nolig@list

\begingroup
\catcode`X\active
\catcode`Y\active
\lccode`[=`{
\lccode`]=`}
\lccode`X=`{
\lccode`Y=`}
\lccode`/=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup
\newcommand*\ActivateVerbatimLigatures{%
  \gdef\@xverbatim##1/end[verbatim]{##1\end{verbatim}}
  \def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\,\do\'}%
}
\newcommand*\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures{%
  \gdef\@xverbatim##1/endXverbatimY{##1\end{verbatim}}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\verbatim@nolig@list\expandafter{%
    \lstfiracode@verbatim@nolig@list
    \do\w\do\*\do\/\do\:\do\=\do\!\do\~\do\[%
    \do\#\do\(\do\?\do\_\do\.\do\;\do\&\do\|%
    \do\+\do\$\do\@\do\%\do\]\do\{\do\}%
  }%
}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ActivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\DeactivateVerbatimLigatures
\begin{verbatim}
A<-www>>=B#{C|}D
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```